# Открыть порт 5000

Tags: linux, centos

Нужно открыть порт 5000 в CentOS.

Добавил порт 5000 в файл

```
/etc/services
testport        5000/tcp   # Application Name
```

Добавил в файрволл

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5000/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Но он до сих пор не работает.
Команда

```
netstat -na |grep 5000
```

его не отображает

Comment: "Открыть порт стеной" и "Ожидать соединений на порту" - несколько разные вещи. Первое делает огнестена, второе делает какое-то (твоё) приложение

Comment: а что же делать? как правильно то?

Comment: Правильно - разрешить firewall'ом входящие соединения на порт и запустить сервис, который принимает эти входящие соединения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Файл [/etc/services](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/services.5.html) это всего лишь "переводчик" имён портов в читабельные буквы:

> services is a plain ASCII file providing a mapping between human-
> friendly textual names for internet services, and their
> underlying assigned port numbers and protocol types

Из этого файла могут браться описания портов всякими инфо/статистика-инструментами.

firewall тоже не "поднимает" порт, а всего лишь открывает доступ к порту (устанавливает правила).

Для того, чтобы можно было приконнектиться к порту нужно убедиться что в firewall не закрыт доступ (и открыть если да) и, ключевое, нужен сервис (программа), который обслуживает этот порт. Например, для стандартного http/https (80/443) как правило на сервере запущен nginx (или apache, или ещё чтототам).

netstat у вас как раз и говорит о том, что 5000го listen-порта у вас нет, его никто не обслуживает.

А дальше уже надо смотреть на постановку задачи. Если задача - "открыть порт в firewall", то вы уже сделали всё что надо.